# About string comparison in nodejs. why is the return value not True?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, web, server

```
else if (pathname === '/reservation_process')
     {
         var body = '';
         request.on('data', function(data){
             body = body + data;
         });

         request.on('end', function(){
             var post = queryString.parse(body);
             console.log(post);
             var customer_id = post.customer_id;
             var customer_phone = post.customer_phone;
             var customer_date = post.customer_date;
             var customer_require = post.customer_require;
             fs.writeFile(`../data/${customer_id}`, customer_phone+'\n'+customer_date+'\n'+customer_require, 'utf8', function(err){
                 response.writeHead(302, {Location:`/`}); //redirection, code 302 means redirection.
                 response.end(); 
             });
         });

     }
```

Input data is stored in /data/%{custmoer_id}, Then the data is made. and....

```
while( i < filelist.length){
                        console.log("filelist : "+i+filelist[i]); 

07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 0.DS_Store
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 1CSS
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 2HTML
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 3JavaScript
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 4mongho
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 5node
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 6test_confirm
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 7undefined
07:40:40 0|main  | filelist : 8김영호
```

Print filelist.

```
else if(pathname === '/reservation_check'){
             var template = templateHTML("영호스튜디오", '<h2>예약확인 페이지</h2>',
             `
             <form action="/reservation_check/show_inf" method="post">
             <p><input type="text" name="confirm_id" placeholder="고객님의 성함"></p>
             <p><input type="text" name="confirm_phone" placeholder="고객님의 연락처"></p>
             <p><input type="submit"></p>
             </from>
             `);
             response.writeHead(200);
             response.end(template);

         }
```

and the form redirect to "/reservation_check/show_inf".

I do compare filelist and post.confirm_id

```
while( i < filelist.length){
if( filelist[i] == post.confirm_id) {
                            console.log("find it!");
                            fs.readFile(`../data/${filelist[i]}`, 'utf8', function(err, data){
                            console.log(data);
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

when I stored data, my input is "김영호" in **customer_id** and in **confirm_id** also "김영호"
So I think filelist[8] == post.confirm_id. 
but `if( filelist[8] == post.customer_id )` return value is false...

i don`t know why return value is false... please help me to solve this problem... :(

and

```
console.log(typeof(post.confirm_id)); 
console.log(typeof(filelist[8])); 
console.log(post.confirm_id); 
console.log(filelist[8]);
```

that result is

```
08:17:41 0|main | string 
08:17:41 0|main | string 
08:17:41 0|main | 김영호 
08:17:41 0|main | 김영호
```

Comment: There might be space characters, or other non-visible characters, in one of the strings.

Comment: It looks like there's a space at the beginning of `filelist[i]` -- your console.log output shows a space after `i` that you didn't put in the arguments.

Comment: Try `if (filelist[i].trim() == post.confirm_id.trim())` to remove surrounding whitespace.

Comment: a space after `i` is what I wrote... sorry for the confusion. 
actually when I print filelist is
`filelist : 1CSS`

Comment: Perhaps print out the code points for each and see what's going on underneath. `customer_id.split("").map(char => char.codePointAt(0)).join("-")`